# How to specify milling in gEDA pcb

Tags: pcb-design, geda

I have a panelized board that I would like to put some nice, rounded corners on, is there a way to specify this so that the g-code can be automatically generated?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you have found the answer by yourself but here it is from my experience: just use the `arc` tool in the outline layer and your PCB manufacturer will know from the gerber file, which shall include the radius and other dimensions used for routing.